# follow through the consequence of

Tags: meaning

> The main criticism of non-realism about God is that it is a thinly
> disguised kind of atheism. To say that God is simply the sum of human
> values is tantamount to saying that God as traditionally conceived
> does not exist; religious language just provides a useful way of
> talking about values in a godless world. This can appear hypocritical,
> since non-realists reject the idea that God has an objective existence
> and yet at the same time want to cling to religious language and
> ritual. It seems more honest to follow through the consequence of
> believing that God doesn’t really exist and become an atheist.

Philosophy: The basics

What does "follow through" in the context mean? Does it mean "accept"?

Comment: *[follow through](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/follow-through) = **take to its logical conclusion, see through to completion***.

Comment: Note that idiomatically we're more likely to [*follow through the **implication***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow+through+the+consequence%2Cfollow+through+the+implication&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfollow%20through%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfollow%20through%20the%20implication%3B%2Cc0) than the ***consequence***, but in practice both would always mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Here 'follow through' means "follow the argument to (what the writer considers to be) its logical conclusion". To 'follow through' in general is to finish something that one has started.

> follow through
>
> — phrasal verb with follow
>
> to continue something until it is
> completed

In the example text provided in the question, Nigel Warburton is saying:

Nonrealist Christians say that God does not exist (he is not 'real'); he is only the sum of human inmagination. They remain, however, in the Church, and cling to Christian ritual (robes, prayers, altars, etc). Warburton asserts that this position is hypocritical, and that nonrealists should follow their argument to its logical conclusion and declare themselves to be atheists.

[Follow through (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/follow-through)

Comment: You don't have to believe in order to enjoy religious ritual and find that religious ceremony enhances your quality of life. Non-believing theologians and church organists are nothing new.

Comment: @RonaldSole - I have been interested in the Sea of Faith movement for some time, although I consider myself an atheist. I was amused by Stoppard's observation that there is no tide in the Aegean. Fr Jude Bullock got drummed out of the RC church, but found a happy home in the CofE, and he sits on local interfaith groups with rabbis and imams, and says he is a 'process theologian'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey (On a rare personal note) I still enjoy listening to the Gregorian chant I learned in another life. Benedicamus Domino!